# RAILS: session is not defined in a module included in application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

In application controller, a module `common_helper` is included:

```
include Commonx::CommonxHelper
```

A method `return_misc_definitions` is defined in `CommonxHelper`:

```
def return_misc_definitions(which_definition)
      Commonx::MiscDefinition.where(:active => true, :for_which => which_definition, :token => session[:token])
end 
module_function :return_misc_definitions
```

Then in controller,  the above method is called:

```
@item_category = Commonx::CommonxHelper.return_misc_definitions('wh_item_category')
```

However there is error in spec:

```
Failure/Error: @item_category = Commonx::CommonxHelper.return_misc_definitions('wh_item_category')

     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `session' for Commonx::CommonxHelper:Module
```

The `session` is not defined! My understanding was that when a method was called from a controller, the session was available in the method since it has been included in application controller . Is this understanding correct?

Comment: I don't think variables that are in the scope of a class will necessarily be available in the scope of modules included within the class. Can you not just pass the session token as a parameter when you call `return_misc_definitions`?

Comment: @PawanAgarawal That's not true, they are definitely available, so long as the module's methods are invoked on the class in which they're included, and not on the module (as in this question).

Comment: Ah, looks like you're right, my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `return_misc_definitions` directly on the `Commonx::CommonxHelper` module rather than as an instance method of the controller. This is why you're getting an undefined variable error on `session` - the `CommonxHelper` itself has no knowledge of `session`, unless it is mixed in (via `include`) as an instance method within a context where `session` is defined.

Since you've `include`d the module in your controller, the following should suffice:

```
@item_category = return_misc_definitions('wh_item_category')
```

Since you're not using `return_misc_definitions` as a module/class method, your `module_function` really isn't doing much here. You can safely remove it.

**EDIT**

Thinking about this more, I don't really think this module is necessary since it doesn't have a useful place outside the context of a controller. Why not just declare `misc_definitions` in `ApplicationController`, or better yet the specific controller that needs it. Perhaps in `ItemsController` or `CategoriesController`?

Comment: So only the instance method of a controller has access to session. I did not know that!

Comment: Almost, views and helper methods should also have access to `session`. ActionView mixes them in from the controller context when rendering views, in a similar approach to the above.

Comment: Is the module_function declaring the method as module(class) method?